# How to change cursor style when hovering the Google Plus One button

Tags: javascript, cursor, google-plus-one

I want to change the cursor style when user hovers the Google "+1" button.
I tried to use the `div` tag and add the `style` attribute, but it's not working.

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" style="cursor:wait" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); 
po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

I guess we need to add something to their js code.

Comment: I want to attract user's attention by changing the common cursor

Comment: See the selector of Plus Button and on :hover style the cursor.
plusselector:hover {}

Comment: why do you use the +1 button? the same reason I want to get their attention, to click the +1. I suppose it's not against g TOS, is it?

Answer (score 2):

+1 is a button with these classes: `class="esw eswd"`, and when hovered, these: `class="esw eswd eswh"`. you can get this element with jQuery and control it:
for example:

```
// with jQuery:
$("button.esw.eswd").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        // your mouseover code here:
        $(this).addClass("some-class");
    },function(){
        // your mouseout code here:
        $(this).removeClass("some-class");
    });
});

///////////////
// or with css:

button.esw.eswd{
    // mouseout style here
}
button.esw.eswd.eswh{
    // mouseover style here
    cursor:wait;
}
```